# Removing background with background picture as calibration

Tags: background-removal

I use an iPhone 8 to take photos of a thin cylinders of rock sitting on the same floor 20 - 30 times a day. The cylinders sit about the centre and run top to bottom, but not exactly the same place each time and colours change.

I have a photo of the bare, black floor too (with a bit of shiny silver table leg on the edges). There is some light reflection too in the black. The rock is rarely shiny and not the same colour as the background.

I would like to remove the floor from the photos in a batch process. The end product is to have long thin pictures I can put on the right hand side of a report page with explanations on the left.

Are there products I can point at the floor photo and then remove it from other photos?

Comment: How deep do you want to dig into this? I'm spectroscopist, and in spectroscopic imaging/hyperspectral imaging we do set up preprocessing procedures to get rid of background pixels. But it may mean training (at least a small) machine learning model... If this is, say, a PhD project or an ongoing study or citizen science or you expect similar situations for the future, it may be well worth the effort.

Comment: @cbeleites unhappy with SX I will look into it. It would involve both object finding and colour ranges to eliminate the background.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any program that will do what you want. There are many programs that will remove auto selected backgrounds, but they are pretty iffy IMO... if your subject is very distinctly different (color/distance/focus/etc) it may work well enough for you. There's even free websites that do it (e.g. [www.remove.bg](https://www.remove.bg)). And there are programs that remove a certain colored BG automatically ("green screen" software).

But I think your best bet will be to use something like PhotoShop.

- Create/save a masked image that removes the BG from one copy.
- Then create an action that auto aligns that image with a new image/layer
  on top, and then applies/duplicates the mask to the top layer; finally
  saving it as a new image.
- Then run the action as a batch function.

The more consistent in composition you can make your images, the easier/better/faster this will work.

Comment: Adobe have put their own AI background remover online - free, just needs a signup. Never tested it on other than people. https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/remove-background

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. I just tried it and it comes closest to isolating the cores / cylinders but included a few objects on the edges.. Might try a batch to cut out the general centre of each image and run those through the Adobe remover.

Comment: @Steven Kersting Thanks, I will muck around with masks and lok at isolating the centre of my photos before trying generic background removers..